# Sharing Cable with multiple devices

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, cable-modem

Comcast has wired our farm so that we have two taps coming off of the telephone pole.  One runs to the barn and one runs to the house.  While we need WiFi access in the barn to handle security camera feeds, we don't need the bandwidth afforded by 2 taps.  We also don't want to pay for two internet subscriptions.

Electrically, the two taps configuration is the cleanest.  When I spoke to the Comcast engineer, he said that there was not electrical continuity between the taps, suggesting that they have active HW on the telephone pole driving each tap.  If I tee one tap and put two terminations on it, the signal theory says that there will be reflections off of the tee and each of the taps making the line more noisy.  However, I know that you can put two cable modems on one cable, for example (See: https://forums.xfinity.com/t5/Your-Home-Network/Using-two-2-internet-cable-modems-on-a-single-service-line/td-p/3297233).  What I want is slightly different:

Can I take the signal from one tap, tee it at the bottom of the telephone pole and connect it to the wire to the barn and wire to the house. (distance from house to pole is 250ft; distance from barn to pole is 250ft; Comcast HW is at top of pole; tee would be at bottom of pole)

Then, in the barn I want to put an access point with a tunnel setup to a corresponding device in the house.  Finally, in the house I would put the comcast access point and have the tunnel set up to route any outgoing traffic to the comcast access point.

Please note that I am aware of other solutions to this problem:

1. I tried power line modems -- they were too finicky/unreliable for the distances involved;
2. I've investigated a line of sight antenna link, but the house is historic and I don't want to put a modern wifi antenna on it.

UPDATE:

As I have considered this more, I've been thinking of it like the LAN in my house. It can have multiple routers, multiple DHCP servers, multiple connections to the internet (see for example: https://www.mushroomnetworks.com/blog/should-you-migrate-your-2-router-2-isp-network-to-a-multi-wan-router-network/). The topology I describe would be reasonable/valid assuming I put a bridge at the point where the cable splits to house and barn.

Since Cable seemed to allow multiple devices on a single wire (is this in fact true? I thought I sited a reference where this was happening), I was hoping people would know of devices that would allow me to do with cable what I could do with my home network.

[image: Picture of before and after]

Comment: Your only solutions for longer range IP communication are wireless (easiest, cheapest, most resilient) or fiber (more expensive, likely faster). There are narrow beam directional antennas for line of sight work that are small and should be easy to be hidden to avoid messing with your home's architectural lines.

Comment: Can someone help me understand why my question is being down-voted?  I had researched that Cable is not point-to-point so that it was possible to put multiple devices on the cable.  I mentioned the signal quality issues that might result from the configuration.  I also provided justification for why I would want such a configuration (not hypothetical case).  What was wrong with my question so that I do not duplicate the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest wireless.  If it's clear line-of-site, get a couple Ubiquiti NanoStation 5AC Loco's ... about $60 each.  If there are tree's and such in the way, maybe use Ubiquiti NanoBeam AC's instead (about $65 each).  5Ghz will be faster, but 2.6Ghz will penetrate solid objects better and may prove more reliable in adverse weather (heavy rain/snow).

These can serve as narrow beam point-to-point network bridges.

Put one on the barn and one on the house.

I have a similar setup using the older Ubiquiti Nanostations and punch through 600' of thick forest between my house and barn.  These are 6 mile antennas... pushing 600' is nothing to them!  I run 2 hi res security cameras across them, along with telephone (voip), and also provide access to several user devices in the barn as well.. ie laptop computer and cell phones... and still have plenty of bandwidth to spare.

Basically the set-up goes something like this:

{ComcastAP/Internet} <---> House Network <---> Nanobeam #1  ~ ~ ~ ~ Nanobeam #2 <---> Barn Network

In the barn, you would have a switch or other wifi router to provide local access to the devices in the barn.